# Javascript object inheritance when objects are properties of other objects?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, tabs, this, javascript-objects

I think I'm beginning to grasp the concept of inheritance when an object is created from another object, but don't understand it when an object is a property of another object. I had all of my code working using a combination of multi-dimensional arrays and objects but not in a real OOP format. Now, in trying to convert it all over to an OOP format, I have a few issues.

In the code example below:

1. Is it possible to reference the `display.index` of the "parent" that contains a `tab` from `method_1` of a `tab`?
2. If `display` has methods, can they be invoked from within a `tab` method and, if so, how?

I think what I'm really trying to get to is a set up in which the objects within an object inherit from the "parent" object even though they were not created from the parent object. Is that possible and, if so, what is it called? I can accomplish the same by using arrays or objects as associative arrays, such as view[0].index, but it appears that a real OOP format ought not to need that.

I realize that I could pass `display.index` to the `tab` constructor make it a property of `tab` and set a `tab` method to a defined `display` method, or `tab` could be created from `display`; but the point was to try to reduce the number of methods on `display` and group them by the "sub"-objects to which they apply.

What is the proper way of accomplishing this?

Thank you.

```
function tab( id )
 {
  this.id = id;
 }

function display( i )
  {
    this.index = i;
    this.tab = new tab(1);
  }
    
 tab.prototype.method_1 = function()
   {
     // Can the display.index that contain tab be referenced here?
     // That is, apart from using view[0].index.
   };

var view = [ new display( 0 ) ];
```

---

I was trying to have each `tab` instance inherit the properties and methods of `display` and then have the `tab` properties and methods as own properties. The code below worked in that `view.tab` inherited the properties and methods of `display` and had the `tab` constructor properties as own properties, but didn't get `method_1` of the constructor. I can add the methods after that but there are many and it would have to be done for each instance of `tab`. I haven't found a method that adds the full result of the constructor like Object.assign does with properties.

The OOP format is interesting but, at this point, I cannot tell if it is more efficient than using multi-dimensional indexes. Instead of having one function that does the same thing to all tabs in a display by operating on a variables of display[ i ].tab[ j ] or just display[ i ][ j ], I end up with separate methods for each tab instance, which are more direct since there are no logic statements testing for differences in tabs based on index j but is it really quicker when it is necessary to search through all the prototypes.

Is starting the tabs off as inheriting from `display` any better than just storing a reference to the `this` of `display` in each `tab` instance? I don't know enough to know if asking for a property through a stored reference to the `this` of `display` is quicker or slower than having a higher prototype and searching through the lower prototypes of `tab` upward until the inherited property is found.

An advantageseems to be that, if I can get it set up correctly to have the tabs inherit methods from the display example, such that they can be invoked as `view.tab.display_method_i.call( view.tab )` is that all the variables are part of the view_tab `this` and the tab index is no longer needed.

```
function tab( id ) { this.id = id; }

function display( i ) { this.index = i; }
    
tab.prototype.method_1 = function() { };

var view = new display( 0 );
view.tab = Object.create( view );
view.tab = Object.assign( view.tab, new tab( 1 ) );
```

Comment: It's a lot more intuitive if you use the `class` syntax which was introduced in 2015. Surely you are not using an older JS implementation than that?

Comment: Thanks. I'm using a recent JS implementation but the MDN document I was reading stated `the class keyword is introduced in ES2015, but is syntactical sugar, JavaScript remains prototype-based` and I figured it would be better to learn the underlying code rather than that made to make it appear as a class in other languages, especially since I'm not familiar with classes either.

Comment: Learning about the prototype system is not a bad idea. In this case you're not using inheritance so the prototype system is not involved. If you want to see how the prototype system works I suggest creating a scenario where you are using inheritance.

Comment: I've been experimenting with inheritance and added an example of it in this case. I understand the general concepts but building the desired objects is a bit challenging and understanding whether or not what appears to be better organization corresopnds to better performance is hard to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can the display.index that contain tab be referenced here?

No - to illustrate, imagine if the instance was also a property of *another* object:

```
const obj = {};
function display(i) {
    this.index = i;
    this.tab = new tab(1);
    obj.tab = this.tab;
}
```

It's a bit contrived, but it still shows the issue - how would the `tab` instance know if its `method_1` it was called from `display` or from `obj`? It can't.

If you need to do something like this, you should pass the information about the parent down to the tab instance somehow:

```js
function tab(id, parentDisplay) {
  this.id = id;
  this.parentDisplay = parentDisplay;
}

function display(i) {
  this.index = i;
  this.tab = new tab(i, this);
}

tab.prototype.method_1 = function() {
  console.log(this.parentDisplay.index);
};

var view = new display(0);
view.tab.method_1();
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `this.tab = new tab(i, this);`? or am I missing something

Comment: Oh, you're right. It wasn't really used anywhere so I didn't see a difference

Comment: Thank you. I see. I'll have multiple instances of `tab` within `display`, and mulitple instances of `display`. I'm likely confusing myself in attempting to eliminate a number of indices and not fully considering how `tab.method_1` will be invoked.  Looking at your example, it appears an index on `display` is not needed because a `view`array will be needed to invoke the method as `view[i].tab.method_1()` based upon whichever `display` is visible. `view = new display(0)` is not useful but `view[0] = new display()` or `view[0] = new display(0)` is.